# Asynchronous error with PCOMM V.14 Automation

Tags: vbscript, hacl

I have some VBscripts that automate IBM Personal Communications

Since I have to use the version 14 (64 bits) sometimes I get errors:

If I use the function CreatObject the error is: The specified module could not be found.

If I use the Wscript method Wscript.CreateObject the error is: WScript.CreateObject: Could not create object named "PCOMM.autECLConnMgr.1"

I have tried 2 ProgID for each of the 4 DLL

"PCOMM.autECLConnMgr" or "PCOMM.autECLConnMgr.1" "PCOMM.autECLPS" or "PCOMM.autECLPS.1" "PCOMM.autECLConnList" or "PCOMM.autECLPS.1" "PCOMM.autECLOIA" or "PCOMM.autECLPS.1"

I'm using LENOVO workstations with Windows 10 Enterprise Build 1809 64 bits

And also tried

C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cscript and C:\Windows\System32\cscript

Both works and both sometimes return the errors

Also have tried 2 different workstations in spite of those machines have the same "image" of software...

With IBM PC Version 12 this didn't happen!

And here is my pain... The error happens just the first time the script runs... Then okay.

I even can't induce the error !!

Any hint would be appreciated.

João

Comment: I forgot to mention that I use the Task Schedule to invoke these scripts through a DOS batch.
I came to the conclusion that the problem is there. 
If called by the Task Schedule, the script behaves as described above.
I tried with and without the Start In option from Task Schedule, and the result is the same.
I also tried with a CMD calling another one and it didn't work.

Comment: More bad news. The problem also happens with VBA !! Even with the PCOMM dll referenced in early biding.